# Can a wildcard ssl certificate be used on a desktop development machine with a self-reported domain name?

Tags: ssl-certificate

We have a wildcard certificate for *.mycompany.com for our server cluster.

I'd like to set up a development environment on my desktop that replicates our server, https and all so I can test some APIs.

If my desktop self-reports its host/domain name, will there be a problem using our certifcate on this machine, let's say https://mylaptop.mycompany.com?

I would only be accessing https://mylaptop.mycompany.com from itself or the LAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically nothing is wrong with that.  But I suggest not to use that production certificate as-is --- I guess your certificate authority signs for your company this certificate for use on production servers only.  You may create your own root CA, with common name say "adapt-dev-testing", and trust this CA only on your devices; then sign server certificates for whatever domain name you would like to use.  Clients do not trust your testing certificate and eliminates any possible problems of trust.

Comment: Thanks.  What problems could be caused by using the real cert on a dev system?  For this system, adding my own root CA would be more involved than just adding it to a browser - backend components make rest calls to other backend components, so a bunch of jdk installations would need the new root CA, too.

Comment: It's a security issue.  If your development system is compromised the private key and certificate in production will have to be replaced immediately. If you don't know right away that your system has been compromised you're leaving your production system at risk until you find out.